# How to password protect VirtualHost directive w/o htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I would like to password protect port 2000 of a web server by embedding a  directive inside of the  directive of the apache config file.  However it didn't prompt for a password as expected.  This is what I had in the apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:2000>
  ServerName www.server.com
  ServerAdmin email
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog logs/server.com-error_log

  <Location / >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "TAP Surveillance"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/s2/.htpasswd-users
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be anything incorrect with your configuration.

- Did you restart apache after configuring this?
- Check your logs for relevant messages.

Comment: I did restart and checked log file.  Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A couple reasons why I think it didn't work:

1. I needed a corresponding NameVirtualHost *:2000 to go with the VirtualHost directive
2. I was using a reverse ssh tunnel on that port so ssh was catching it before the web server.  The web server that the tunnel connected to did not have password protection.

So now my question is how to password protect the server at the end of the tunnel.  It is a simple server and not capable of passwords.  That's why I was hoping to protect access to it via the apache server.

Comment: Umm, don't allow the tunnel and have all access go through Apache?  You have to detail the architecture a bit more to get a reasonable answer, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please try: location and DocumentRoot need identical

```
<VirtualHost *:2000>
   ServerName www.server.com
   ServerAdmin email
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   ErrorLog logs/server.com-error_log
   <Location /var/www/html >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "TAP Surveillance"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/s2/.htpasswd-users
    Require valid-user
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, restart Apache